# Hosting flask API

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, sqlalchemy, heroku-postgres

Please forgive me if some of my terminology is off here, I'm new to all of this.

I have built a python-flask API that GETs data from my PostgreSQL database. I have tried to get my API hosted on Heroku but I think it is unsuccessful because my API is using my postgres username and password to connect to localhost. Will I need to get my database hosted first before I can host my API on Heroku.

Thanks

**app.py**

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template
from flask_cors import CORS
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

# Postgres username, password, and database name
username = 'postgres'
password = 'XXXXXXXXXX' # postgres password
host = 'localhost'
port = '5432'
database = 'test'

# string that contains necessary postgres login info
postgres_str = ('postgresql://{username}:{password}@{ipaddress}:{port}/{database}'
                .format(username=username,
                        password=password,
                        ipaddress=host,
                        port=port,
                        database=database
                        ))
               
# create the connection
conn = create_engine(postgres_str)

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app=app)

@app.route('/bamboo/<product>', methods=['GET'])
def getProducts(product):

    # GET request
    if request.method == 'GET':
        
        query = """select a.*, b.logo
                   from products a
                   left join companies b on a.company_name = b.company_name
                   where CAST(product_price as int) != 0
                   """
        
        df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)

        final_results = df.to_json(orient='records')

        return final_results  # serialize and use JSON headers


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run!
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You need to host the database first. You can use [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#download-and-install) for that.

So first go into your terminal and login into your Heroku account using the following command and press Enter, and you will see a successful logged in message with your account name.

```
$ heroku login
```

Now create a Database for your app using the following command,

```
$ heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev --app app_name
```

Now after your Database has been created, get the URL of your Database using the following command,

```
$ heroku config --app app_name
```

Please refer [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku) and [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-python) for more info.